# Unary minus for decimal in Linq-to-SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

When I do `.Select(a => new { a.b, a.c, -a.d })` it says `Could not translate expression… into SQL and could not treat it as a local expression.` If I remove `-` - it works okay. Is there any way to do unary minus in Linq-to-SQL? I also tried `0 - a.d` with no luck.

Comment: Well, this error doesn't happen with Entity Framework. You might want to consider that Linq-To-Sql is essentially on life-support.  It hasn't seen any improvements for many years and will, of course, never see any in the future.

Comment: The error message I get when I try this is more informative `Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.`

Answer (score 0):

Strange,

if I do something similar like:

```
      var xyz = (from u in db.tb_ir_sometable
                 where u.Volgorde == 1
                 select new { a = -u.Volgorde }).ToList();
```

it works like a charm. Is your field numeric??

**Perhaps it is because you do not use X = -a.d ??**

Comment: the ToList is just to enforce immediate execution